# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request') | newscatcher API & Google Maps API using axios library

Tags: jquery, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, axios, request

I am doing a little side project for summer and running into this issue that I just can't seem to figure out.

In my project, I'm using the Google Maps API to generate routes. There's a function called `calculateRoute()` that runs when a button is clicked, and it returns the `route.summary` variable. This variable is then passed as a parameter to the `fetchData(routeName)` function, which is located in another file.

How I've written calculateRoute():

```
async function calculateRoute() {
if (originRef.current.value === "" || destinationRef.current.value === "") {
  return;
}
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
const results = await directionsService.route({
  origin: originRef.current.value,
  destination: destinationRef.current.value,
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
  provideRouteAlternatives: true,
});

setDirectionsResponse(results);
setRoutes(results.routes);
setDistance(results.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
setDuration(results.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
getNow();

Promise.all(
  routes.map(async (route) => {
    console.log(route.summary);
    const dataset = await fetchData(route.summary);
    // Perform any further processing with the fetched data here
    console.log('Fetched Data:', dataset);
    return dataset;
  })
)
  .then((data) => {
    setDangerLevel(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    setDangerLevel([]);
  });}
```

The objective is to utilize the `fetchData()` function, which I created using the [newscatcher API](https://docs.newscatcherapi.com/code-snippets/your-first-call#node.js-axios), to analyze news headlines related to the generated route. I followed the API call example provided on the newscatcher website while implementing this function. I also purely used `axios` instead of the standard `fetch()` API because the document covered API calls using `axios`.

fetchData():

```
    const axios = require("axios").default;
    
    async function fetchData(routeName) {
        console.log(routeName);
        console.log("Reached fetchData function");
        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.newscatcherapi.com/v2/search',
            params: { q: `"${routeName}" AND Toronto`, lang: 'en', sort_by: 'relevancy', page: '1', page_size: '30', countries: "CA", from: "3 day ago", to: "today" },
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': '//my-API-Key'
            }
        };
    
        return axios.request(options)
            .then(function (response) {
                // The response.data is already a JavaScript object representing JSON data
                var jsonData = response.data;
    
                // Extract the 'summary' from each article and put it into a dataset (array)
                var dataset = jsonData.articles.map(article => {
                    return { summary: article.summary };
                });
                const filteredDataset = dataset.filter(item => item.summary.includes(`${routeName}`));
                filteredDataset.forEach(item => {
                    item.summary = item.summary.replace(/\n/g, '');
                });
                // Return the dataset
                console.log(filteredDataset);
                return filteredDataset;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return [];
            });
    }

module.exports = fetchData;
```

The problem arises when I attempt to execute this code sequence via the button click. Although the `route.summary` variable is correctly passed, I encounter an error related to the "**request**" from the axios library, which doesn't seem to be functioning properly.

If anyone has any insights on how to address this issue, I'd greatly appreciate your help.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJjno.png)